# how to install onnxruntime on raspberry pi 4

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

I want to setup onnxruntime python library on raspberry pi 3  and I tried some ways to install it but I couldn't . the ways that I followed are :
1 - [way 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59715507/how-to-load-or-infer-onnx-models-in-edge-devices-like-raspberry-pi)
2 - [way 2](https://github.com/nknytk/built-onnxruntime-for-raspberrypi-linux/blob/master/BUILD.md)
3 - using pip3
I want to know is there any other way to install it ?

Thanks :)

Comment: So you tried a couple of methods that should theoretically work, but, apparently it did not work for you... What problems did you run into? Please update your question with additional information. BTW: title says Pi4, but question says Pi3. Please state correct model. Also add detaul about OS + version, etc

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: try https://github.com/nknytk/built-onnxruntime-for-raspberrypi-linux